# Rails No route matches [DELETE]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oop

Trying to delete a reply

```
 <% @comment.replies.each do |reply| %>
 <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment_replies_path(reply), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%></td>
```

I do receive the following error

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/comments/66/replies"
```

rake routes

```
comment_reply_path  
          DELETE    /comments/:comment_id/replies/:id(.:format)   replies#destroy
```

The url that I am at this point is

```
http://localhost:3000/comments/66/replies
```

routes.rb

```
resources :comments do
   resources :replies
end
```

Comment: And what's in your routes.rb?

Comment: @SebastianPalma updated

Answer (score 0):

Your route says comment_reply_path and you are using comment_replies_path

You need to update your code to use correct path helper

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', comment_reply_path(reply), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to do this

Comment: have you link like this
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', comment_reply_path(reply), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>